# methods to identify whether a function is unimodal or multi

Tags: real-analysis, functions, optimization

A scalar valued function $f(x_1,...,x_n)$ can have single minima or multiple local minima. How to determine this by doing some computationally efficient tests? Assume that $f(.)$ is non-differentiable. So how to confirm that there is single or multiple minima?

To make sense out of this question, if needed please assume simplifying characteristics for well-behavedness of the function and point out why it's needed?

Comment: You cannot, for precisely the example you give. You have to have more assumptions on the functions to say anything. If you keep asking me to give function values for a function only I know, and I keep answering with the value 2, how could you ever know that there is no point where the value is 5?

Comment: ok i changed the question now. only assume that the function is non-differentiable but continuous.

Comment: Bounded domain, lipschitz etc? What if the function value increases drastically when $x_4$ is around $10^{500}$

Comment: yes assume bounded, lipschitz. One reason behind posing the question is also to know exactly all these conditions that must be specified before that question can be answered reasonably. I have added this point above.

Comment: With those, you can at-least grid the region, and get bounds on the best possible in relation to what you currently have. You will never be able to do it efficiently though. Already in the simple case of an indefinite quadratic over a polytope, it is just as hard to figure out if a solution is the globally optimal, as it is to find the globally optimal solution.

Comment: are there any other sophisticated techniques written in some research papers?

Comment: To get anywhere, you have to define very clearly which class of function you are addressing. As I said, already the case of nonconvex quadratic programming is intractable. There are no generic methods to test if a point is locally or globally optimal.